# repeatcell request not updating cell properties in Google Sheets

Tags: php, api, google-sheets-api

My Google Sheets PHP API `repeatcell` request is not updating cell properties.

Is there any working alternative to update cell properties like Text bold, background color, etc.?

Is there any proper documentation of the Google Spreadsheet PHP API?

I am using "google/apiclient": "^2.0".

This is the code I used and the response I received:

```
$sheetId = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId, ['ranges' => 'SLA Data!A1']);
    $range = new Google_Service_Sheets_GridRange();
    $range->setSheetId($sheetId->sheets[0]->properties->sheetId);
    $range->setEndRowIndex(2);
    $range->setEndRowIndex(5);
    $range->setStartColumnIndex(0);
    $range->setEndColumnIndex(5);
    $cell = new Google_Service_Sheets_CellData();
    $cellFormat = new Google_Service_Sheets_CellFormat();
    $textFormat = new Google_Service_Sheets_TextFormat();
    $textFormat->setBold(true);
    $cellFormat->setTextFormat($textFormat);
    $cell->setUserEnteredFormat($cellFormat);
    $repeatCell = new Google_Service_Sheets_RepeatCellRequest();
    $repeatCell->setRange($range);
    $repeatCell->setFields('userEnteredFormat.textFormat.bold');
    $requests = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
    $requests->setRepeatCell($repeatCell);

    $batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    $batchUpdateRequest->setRequests($requests);
```

Response Code:

```
Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse Object
(
[collection_key:protected] => replies
[repliesType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_Response
[repliesDataType:protected] => array
[spreadsheetId] => 1ZlQPGuI0q0bIDAsbl04BALb8_sqXm02aPY0ZCEyeTHc
[updatedSpreadsheetType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_Spreadsheet
[updatedSpreadsheetDataType:protected] => 
[internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[modelData:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[processed:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[replies] => Array
    (
        [0] => Google_Service_Sheets_Response Object
            (
                [addBandingType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_AddBandingResponse
                [addBandingDataType:protected] => 
                [addChartType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_AddChartResponse
                [addChartDataType:protected] => 
                [addDimensionGroupType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_AddDimensionGroupResponse
                [addDimensionGroupDataType:protected] => 
                [addFilterViewType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_AddFilterViewResponse
                [addFilterViewDataType:protected] => 
                [addNamedRangeType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_AddNamedRangeResponse
                [addNamedRangeDataType:protected] => 
                [addProtectedRangeType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_AddProtectedRangeResponse
                [addProtectedRangeDataType:protected] => 
                [addSheetType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_AddSheetResponse
                [addSheetDataType:protected] => 
                [createDeveloperMetadataType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_CreateDeveloperMetadataResponse
                [createDeveloperMetadataDataType:protected] => 
                [deleteConditionalFormatRuleType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_DeleteConditionalFormatRuleResponse
                [deleteConditionalFormatRuleDataType:protected] => 
                [deleteDeveloperMetadataType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_DeleteDeveloperMetadataResponse
                [deleteDeveloperMetadataDataType:protected] => 
                [deleteDimensionGroupType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_DeleteDimensionGroupResponse
                [deleteDimensionGroupDataType:protected] => 
                [duplicateFilterViewType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_DuplicateFilterViewResponse
                [duplicateFilterViewDataType:protected] => 
                [duplicateSheetType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_DuplicateSheetResponse
                [duplicateSheetDataType:protected] => 
                [findReplaceType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_FindReplaceResponse
                [findReplaceDataType:protected] => 
                [updateConditionalFormatRuleType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateConditionalFormatRuleResponse
                [updateConditionalFormatRuleDataType:protected] => 
                [updateDeveloperMetadataType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateDeveloperMetadataResponse
                [updateDeveloperMetadataDataType:protected] => 
                [updateEmbeddedObjectPositionType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateEmbeddedObjectPositionResponse
                [updateEmbeddedObjectPositionDataType:protected] => 
                [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [modelData:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [processed:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you haven't set cell to the repeatCell request. Add this line after repeatCell initialization

```
$repeatCell->setCell($cell);
```

Now it will update the sheet